# forwarding emails via postfix, smart routine to actively check that it works

Tags: linux, ubuntu, postfix, forwarding

I have a domain registered at `namecheap` and run my website on a `digitalocean` droplet.

I have successfully set up email forwarding on the server with `postfix`, such that emails sent to `name@example.com` are now being forwarded to another email account I own.

I followed [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-as-a-send-only-smtp-server-on-ubuntu-14-04) for the initial `postfix` setup and then adjusted the configuration according to [this blog post](https://www.andreagrandi.it/2014/08/31/getting-started-with-digital-ocean-vps-configuring-dns-and-postfix-for-email-forwarding/) in order to activate the forwarding. Everything works fine as of now.

My question is: How can I automatically and actively check that everything will keep on working in the future, despite me maybe fiddling with the server or something like that. Any smart suggestions for setting up some automatic check (without having to send an email to myself every day)?

I want to be able to rule out that I can unknowingly make any changes to the server in such a way that I break the forwarding pipeline through the server.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `I simply want to be able to be super certain that I can give out the name@example.com address to people and know that I can be reached via that address.` Then email is the wrong medium for you. And in fact, sending you a test mail is the **best** way to check mail delivery This can be automated and incoming mails can be filtered ...

Comment: `Then email is the wrong medium for you.` Because you say so or because of any actual reason?

Comment: SMTP gives no guarantees at all. Email *never* was a reliable medium.

Comment: Okay, fair enough. Let's say I simply want it to be as probable as an email sent directly to the address I am now forwarding to. That means, I simply want to rule out the potential failures on the way through my server. I will edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by Sven, email is not a 100% reliable system.  That said, there are a couple of things you can do to make sure you're as close to 100% as possible.

I would suggest that you put your Postfix config files into a configuration management app such as git, Mercurial, Subversion, etc.  This will allow you to identify a known working config and can easily identify what change has caused your mail system to break.

Additionally, you could write a cron job on *another* machine to send you mail once a week(or every day...).  Or sign up for a service that will send you a mail every day.